# Azure File Share permissions?

Tags: file-sharing, azure

I have created a file share in Microsoft Azure. I have looked but not been able to find if there is any way to create permissions on the file share created. Or is it a open file share where anyone who has access can view everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use shared access signatures (SAS) to give permissions to your Azure File Share.

> A shared access signature (SAS) provides you with a way to grant
>   limited access to objects in your storage account to other clients,
>   without exposing your account key. More information about SAS please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1).

Azure File storage service is not designed to provide external users access to files. It's primary purpose is to act as a file share for cloud services and virtual machines running in Azure.

You should use Shared Access Signatures to share files with external users.

Comment: yes we saw that option however it wasn't the granular permissions we were looking for so we abandoned the effort

Comment: @GoldenWest You could give a [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage) to Azure that you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

Azure just enabled a preview of Azure File Share Sync.  You can sync shares on premise to Azure File Shares and permissions are transferred. Then you can setup a new server in Azure to make available to users with permissions intact.  I put [this blog post](https://www.myworkdrive.com/cloud-storage/) together on it.

Comment: Read over ["Why do I need 50 reputation to comment"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) to ensure you understand how you can start commenting.